# What is Cache Tagging?

Tags: php, performance, caching, kohana

There is [Cache_Tagging](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Cache_Tagging) in Kohana but it does not explain what it is. Can anyone tell what Cache Tagging is supposed to do or when do we use it ?

Comment: You are linking to localhost...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: sorry, thanks for updating :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some cache implementations allow you to add one or more tags to any data item you store in the cache, and then find or delete all items with a given tag. This can be useful for a number of things, most significantly batch updates (you add a bunch of related stuff to the cache, tag it with a version string, and when you later learn that data from that version has become outdated, tell the cache to drop it all at once).

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you can set tags to cache entries and then delete cache entries by tag (s ?).
That way, you're able to clear part of the cache very selectively, with your own rules.