# Redis: cache item invalidation based on dependencies?

Tags: caching, redis, lua, stackexchange.redis, distributed-caching

Is there a native way in Redis to invalidate a cache item when other specified items get removed from the cache? Is there an eviction policy based on dependencies?

Here is an example of what I want to accomplish.

Let's say in Redis we have a cache item whose key is **mainKey**. I would like this item to be automatically removed if another specific item gets removed. If ,for example, **mainKey** has dependencies on the keys **d1** and **d2**, then I would like **mainKey** to be removed from the cache as soon as either **d1** or **d2** is removed from the cache.

In .Net, for example, something like this is fairly easy to code using MemoryCache.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCacheItemIsRemovedWhenADependencyGetsRemoved() {
    // ARRANGE

    var cache = new MemoryCache(name: "MyCache");

    // insert dependencies cache items
    var dummyValue = 1;
    cache.Set("d1", dummyValue, absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
    cache.Set("d2", dummyValue, absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

    // build cache policy for main cache item
    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy {
        SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
    };
    var dependencies = new[] { "d1", "d2" };
    var changeMonitor = cache.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(dependencies);
    policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(changeMonitor);

    // insert main cache item
    cache.Set("mainKey", "this is the main value", policy);

    // ACT

    // remove a dependency key
    cache.Remove("d1");

    // ASSERT

    // mainKey is removed as a consequence of removing "d1"
    Assert.IsFalse(cache.Contains("mainKey"));
    // only "d2" remains in the cache
    Assert.AreEqual(1, cache.GetCount());
    Assert.IsTrue(cache.Contains("d2"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known obstacle in cache invalidation and you need [Cache Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332475/what-is-cache-tagging) to overcome it.

> for example, mainKey has dependencies on the keys d1 and d2, then I would like mainKey to be removed from the cache as soon as either d1 or d2 is removed from the cache.

TL;DR - You need to tag keys that are dependent on each other, and when some action (update or delete) occurs to one of them, you would need to remove all the cached items that are sharing the the same tag.